# Eclipse ADT ListView and GridView Rendering is disabled

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview, android-listview, adt

ADT said that version 11 brings ListView and GridView Rendering, however it's disabled in my eclipse and shows: "not supported for this SDK version; try changing the Render Target".

I tried changing the render target but no help there.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure, that you have included in android manifest something like that:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

targetSdkVersion is parameter determining which API level will be used by your applicaton.
minSdkVersion indicates if device will be able to install your app, but you have to ensure, that all API incompatibilities are handled by you manually in code (i.e. by reflections)

Answer (score 0):

Today i simple update all my environment and Android SDK and it works good when i create Android project on SDK-13 (Android 3.2). SDK-11 and SDK-12 not support it for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try uninstalling, then reinstalling Eclipse. I may be misunderstanding your question, though.